# Accepted safe/future-proof way to parse /proc/%d/stat?

Tags: c, linux, parsing, procfs

The second field of Linux `/proc/%d/stat` files is a command name enclosed in parentheses, which itself might contain parentheses as part of the command. What is the correct way to deal with this when parsing the `stat` pseudo-files? My inclination would be to find the last `')'` (e.g. using `strrchr` on the whole file contents) but I'm concerned this might not be future-proof against addition of new fields at the end. Is there any documentation of the correct way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for the last ) is the best way to go about it and will most likely be future-proof.

`strrchr` is used for parsing in the [procps source](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/proc/readproc.c?view=markup#l383) (the ps family of functions, `ps`, `top`, `kill`, etc).

```
S = strchr(S, '(') + 1;
tmp = strrchr(S, ')');
num = tmp - S;
if(unlikely(num >= sizeof P->cmd)) num = sizeof P->cmd - 1;
memcpy(P->cmd, S, num);
P->cmd[num] = '\0';
S = tmp + 2;                 // skip ") "
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the citation answers that matter. +1 and accepted.